# SilverStripe class 'SpamProtectorField' not found in RecaptchaField.php

Tags: php, composer-php, silverstripe

I'm upgrading to SilverStripe 3.1.13 from 3.0.x . I've updated my composer.json as such:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "silverstripe/cms": "3.1.*",
    "silverstripe/framework": "3.1.*",
    "silverstripe/recaptcha": "*",
    "silverstripe/spamprotection": "*",
}
```

Along with several other unrelated requirements.

sileverstipe/recaptcha requires the spamprotection module.

silverstripe/modules/recaptcha/code/RecaptchaField.php indeed extends SpamProtectorField.

With my SilverStripe 3.0 installation the SpamProtection module v1.0.x-dev had a SpamProtectorField.php file with the SpamProtectorField class defined as an abstract class, but that version requires silverstripe/framework 3.0.* . The SpamProtectorField.php file is not available in Packagist silverstripe/spamprotection v1.2.0 or v2.0.0 which use silverstripe/framework 3.1.* .

I could probably just create the SpamProtectorField.php file in my code directory and get past this error, but is this the best course of action? Should that file be a part of one of these other modules.

Comment: The latest SilverStripe Recaptcha module doesn't need SpamProtectorField to work. You shouldn't create a SpamProtectorField to get this to work. Are you getting an error when trying to run your code? Or is the Recaptcha just not showing up? Are you using this with a UserDefinedForm or a custom form page?

Comment: I get this message when I run /dev/build
Fatal error: Class 'SpamProtectorField' not found in C:\Users\dkolodziejczyk\SS_Sites\ss-github31\silverstripe\modules\recaptcha\code\RecaptchaField.php on line 25

Comment: Check the code in your `RecaptchaField.php` on line 25. If you are using the [latest version](https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha/blob/master/code/RecaptchaField.php) it should say `class RecaptchaField extends FormField`. Sounds like the one you have is an older version that extends `SpamProtectorField`.

Comment: I changed my composer.json to require
"silverstripe/recaptcha": "1.2.x-dev",
and changed minimum-stability to 'dev'
This cleared up the error, but I'm now using a bunch of dev level modules.

Comment: I'm guessing that because the latest branch of the Recaptcha module has a build error that composer treats that branch as having dev stability right now.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of the [SilverStripe Recaptcha module](https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha) for SilverStripe 3.1 does not require a `SpamProtectionField` to work.

Previous versions of the module had `RecaptchaField` extend `SpamProtectionField`. [`RecaptchaField`](https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha/blob/master/code/RecaptchaField.php#L25) now extends `FormField`.

If you have latest version of SilverStripe Recaptcha module and the SpamProtection module you should not get any errors regarding a `SpamProtectionField`.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the stable version of silverstripe/recaptcha does not work with the stable version of silverstripe/spamprotection.  However, the dev version of recaptcha does work and you can get it by specifying it in composer.json as follows:

```
"silverstripe/recaptcha": "1.2.*-dev"
```

Note that the "-dev" suffix applies only to recaptcha.  Other components with no suffix continue to use whatever minimum-stability you specified, or if minimum-stability is omitted, the default is stable.

Maybe at the time of reading, the -dev suffix is no longer necessary.  To see if the fixed code has been released to stable, check here to see there is a tag newer than 1.2.0:
https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha/tags

Or check here to see if it has been deployed to packagist, from where composer gets files.
https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/recaptcha